# Javascript weird syntax

Tags: javascript

So I was programming some stuff in Javascript and some time later I saw I made a typo in the following piece of code:

```
(function() {

    var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'),l    <-----
        someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');

    someEl.onclick = function() {
       ...
    };

})();
```

Notice how the `l` isn't supposed to be there. I've only tested this in Firefox but, why didn't I get a syntax error?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think you can define more than one variable in javacript by using commas. So basically what you did was define the variable `someEl` and initalised it (by setting a value), and also created a variable named `l`

Comment: @fin1te: But I didn't put a semicolon after I declared `l`. Shouldn't that be a syntax error?

Comment: [Nope](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to create two variables inside the `var`-statement:

```
var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'),
    someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');
```

The introduction of the comma meant that you created `someEl` and `l`:

```
var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'),l
```

Semicolons at the end of JS lines are optional, so now you have a distinct, second line of code afterwards:

```
    someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');
```

And this is valid because you can assign to variables without explicitly `var`-ing them (albeit imbuing slightly different semantics to your program).

Comment: Without "var" is implicitly declared as a global, so it can be a major pain to track down.

Comment: @jishi: Yes it can, and worse you never know whether you might be overwriting a variable already declared elsewhere! Whew!

Answer (score 1):

since ending lines with semi colons is not mandatory this code is being evaluated like this:

```
var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'), l;
someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is valid since semicolons are not mandatory.

`someEl` and `l` would be local variables

`someOtherEl` would be global since it now has no var

`l` would be *undefined*.

Use console/alert to see it.

```
var a,b,c;
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally created three variables: `someEl`, `l` and `someOtherEl`

The new line denotes a new statement in this instance.

If you put them all on the same line, eg:

```
var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'),l someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');
```

you'd get `Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier`, as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to

```
var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el');
var l;
someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');
```

Which is not really a syntax error in stricter languages either, but it would perhaps give a warning about an unused variable in compiled languages.

JavaScript is very forgiving, which can sometimes give some interesting debugging sessions as it happily accepts a undefined variable (that may were a typo for another variable) suddenly appearing anywhere.

Comment: `someOtherEl` is missing the `var` qualifier, so it's not _quite_ the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed just after I submitted it.. fixed now

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Really? JavaScript shorthand syntax is weirder than I remembered. ;) Been a while since I actually coded directly in JavaScript... (Using GWT currently)

Comment: @Stein: [Trust Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). :)

Answer (score -1):

Although the code you've written is technically valid, JSLint will report it as a warning.

> Problem at line 1 character 56:
>   Expected ';' and instead saw
>   'someOtherEl'.
>
> `var someEl = document.getElementById('id-of-some-el'),l`
>
> Problem at line 2 character 9:
>   'someOtherEl' was used before it was
>   defined.
>
> `someOtherEl = document.getElementById('some-other-el');`

Comment: Only with strict checks on. These are more like "warnings" than errors.

Comment: Good point, bad semantics on my part. Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: Better. Still doesn't really answer the question, though.. :)

Comment: Yeah, on further reflection this would have been much more suitable as a comment rather than an answer. What can I say... it's Monday.